# How can i change the size of an iframe with a radiobox on the fly?

Tags: jquery, iframe, size

I want users to switch the size of an iframe using a radio check box, how can i do this?

I tried something like that
For the radiocheckboxes i did thensomething like this:

```
<input id="othersize1" type="radio" name="size"reSize(60,400) onclick="" checked="checked" /><label for="othersize1">60x400</label>
<input id="othersize2" type="radio" name="size" onclick="reSize(1280,400)" /><label for="othersize2">1280x400</label>
```

The iframe:

```
<iframe src="myphphere.php">Your browser don't supports iframes.</iframe>
```

Comment: Show what you've done so far.

Comment: Please show some sort of effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`jQuery`](http://www.jquery.com).

Here is a basic example I just made:

HTML:

```
<iframe id="iframe1" src="http://meatballcandy.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/nicholas-cage-as-et.png">
    <p>Not Supported</p>
</iframe>

<div>
    <input id="item1" type="radio" name="size" value="100" checked="checked" /><label for="item1">100x100</label>
    <input id="item2" type="radio" name="size" value="200" /><label for="item2">200x200</label>
    <input id="item3" type="radio" name="size" value="300" /><label for="item3">300x300</label>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        $('#iframe1').css({
            'height': $(this).val() + 'px',  
            'width': $(this).val() + 'px'
        });
    });
});
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/fYP2Z/1/